# difference between 'global varName' and 'self.varName' in python

Tags: python, class, global-variables

what is the use of writing 'global varName' in the body of constructor ?
I mean we can achive the same goal by writting 'self.varName' ?  For Example

```
class Mine_Global:
    def __init__(self):
        global varName
        varName = 3
        self.newInsVar = 7

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global varName
    obj1 = Mine_Global()
    print varName, obj1.newInsVar;
    varName = varName + 2
    print varName, obj1.newInsVar;

    obj2 = Mine_Global()
    print varName, obj2.newInsVar
```

Comment: Don't use global for class variables!

Answer (score 1):

If `varName` talks about instance's property and instances may have different values for `varName` then use `self.var`.

If `varName` talk about module and all the classes of that module and all the instances of classes should share same value of `varName` then use `global varName`

Comment: I didn't get your point !!! can u please elaborate you answer ..